# Disable Button in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, button, input, components

I want if the input 'Contract type' is empty, the button 'Save' is not clickable

Save button:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <cic-textbox [control]="formGroup.get('contractType')"></cic-textbox>
      </div>
```

ALL Buttons:

```
 <div class="cic-header-actions pull-left" *ngIf="actions && actions.length > 
 0">
      <button class="btn btn-{{action.style}} m-l-xs" *ngFor="let action of actions" ng-disabled="!contractTypeValid" (click)="execute(action)">
          <cic-icon [icon]="action.icon"></cic-icon>
          {{action.text }}
        </button>
    </div>
```

Definition contractType:

```
 let contractType: DataDictionaryPropertyExtended = {
            Binding: 'VART:BEZEICHNUNG',
            Label: 'Vertragsart',
            LabelCols: 4,
            ContentCols: 8,
            IsDisabled: this.isDisabled,
            ValidationProperties: [
                <ValidationProperty>{
                    Type: ValidationType.IsNotEmpty,
                    ErrorMessage: 'Vertragsart darf nicht leer sein.',
                }
            ]
        };
```

BUTTON SAVE GREEN:

[image]

Comment: I have some problem understanding what button should be disabled. I would have answered this question like Robin below, so what is wrong with that answer? Could you perhaps create a plunker, now we can only see some code fragments and at least I am having trouble to recreate and understand the issue with code provided...

Answer (score 156):

Change `ng-disabled="!contractTypeValid"` to `[disabled]="!contractTypeValid"`

Comment: Now both are not clickable. A binding to the input still does not exist

Comment: both are not clickable because you render your buttons with a `*ngFor`, you need to get the disabled state from your action object.
You can add some code that determines if the action is a submit or cancel action and set the `isDisabled` attribute of your action object to true or false.

Answer (score 27):

I tried use `[disabled]="!editmode"` but it not work in my case.

This is my solution `[disabled]="!editmode ? 'disabled': null"` , I share for whom concern.

```
<button [disabled]="!editmode ? 'disabled': null" 
    (click)='loadChart()'>
            <div class="btn-primary">Load Chart</div>
    </button>
```

Stackbliz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-af55ep