# Initially input field not mandatory but still submit button disabled?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I check input field validation like below. Some data input field needs to be filled and the button should be disabled. In mandatory case it works fine (console.log -> called 1) .but the else part it calls, but button shows as disabled. When I type and clear something in the input field it enables. need some expert help to fix this.

```
isCommentMandatory(Reviews: ReviewModel[]): void {
      if (Reviews.length > 0) {
          console.log("called ...1 ");
          this.isCommentRequired = false;
          this.DetailForm = this.fb.group({
            comment: [''],
            rate: ['']
          });
        } else {
          console.log("called ...2 ");
          this.isCommentRequired = true;
          this.DetailForm = this.fb.group({
            comment: ['', Validators.required],
            rate: ['']
          });
        }
      }
```

and called it like this,

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  
       this.DetailModel$.pipe().subscribe((opd => {
          this.detail = opd as Detail;
          const date = this.detail?.time;
          const planDate = date !== undefined ? date : new Date();
          //according date select reviews data
          this.store.select(selectAllReviewsDetailsModel(planDate)).
            subscribe(res => this.Reviews = res);
    
          //need to call after change Details
          this.isCommentMandatory(this.Reviews);
        }));
      }
```

In the html template it bind has below,

```
<mat-form-field>
            <input matInput formControlName="comment" [type]="'text'"
               [required]="isCommentRequired"
              [readonly]="false" [spaced]="false">
          </mat-form-field>
     <at-sticky-footer>
            <button *ngIf="selectedId$|async" [disabled]="!(DetailModel.valid && (DetailModel.dirty))" (click)="submit()">submit</button>
      </at-sticky-footer>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe If you change your code to this, will help.

```
ngOnInit(): void {

   this.DetailModel$.pipe(
      switchMap(opd => {
          this.detail = opd as Detail;
          const date = this.detail?.time;
          const planDate = date !== undefined ? date : new Date();

          //according date select reviews data
          return this.store.select(selectAllReviewsDetailsModel(planDate))
      })).subscribe(res => {
             this.Reviews = res;

             //need to call after change Details
             this.isCommentMandatory(this.Reviews);
      });
  }
```

With that change, `isCommentMandatory()` will run after `store.select`

For more:

> [SwitchMap - Rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)

Comment: thank you so much. I will try this and check it working,

Comment: You are welcome. Is a good practise to avoid nested subscriptions as possible.
Don't forget to import `switchMap` from Rxjs library

Comment: i try it , but same as it also. when I try and clear filed button enable.. initaly it disable

Comment: Can you share a stackblitz to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I will try , but this is part of lard code base. actually , i need ,when data loading, enable button , if -> comment input field not mandotory. the mandotory case work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved when remove '`(DetailModel.dirty)'`